# VBA Updating Source Data for Pivot Table to end of row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to figure out how to update my pivot table source data to the end of row when the data changes using VBA. My current code is below:

```
Dim shBrandPivot As Worksheet
Dim shCurrentWeek As Worksheet
Dim shPriorWeek As Worksheet
Dim shPivot As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long


Set shBrandPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Brand Pivot")
Set shCurrentWeek = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Week")
Set shPriorWeek = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Prior Week")
Set shPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot")
lr = shCurrentWeek.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot").Activate

ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CurrentWeek!A3:X & lr"

End With
```

The error I am getting is Run time error 1004: Cannot open PivotTable source file: E:\offline\KXM2103\Data\CurrentWeek

Comment: is it possible to use a dynamically defined range and then simply refresh your pivot table in your code? how is your data getting updated?

Comment: @scott for now, my data is being manually updated by going to Options -> Change source data. I'm thinking of attempting the approach you discussed but I wanted to see if there was a way to exclusively do it through VBA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it exclusively in VBA you can try this.

```
Dim shBrandPivot As Worksheet
Dim shCurrentWeek As Worksheet
Dim shPriorWeek As Worksheet
Dim shPivot As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
dim rng as range

Set shBrandPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Brand Pivot")
Set shCurrentWeek = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Week")
Set shPriorWeek = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Prior Week")
Set shPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot")
lr = shCurrentWeek.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
set rng = shcurrentweek.range("A3:X" & lr)

With shPivot.PivotTables(1).PivotCache 
        .SourceData = rng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
        .Refresh
End With
```

Comment: I am getting a compile error on the xlPivotTableVersion14 (variable not defined)

Comment: edited it to just remove the version and stick with the default

Comment: What line?  Do you have a pivottable on your sheet("pivot")

Comment: Yes I have a pivot table. I'm receiving it on sheets("pivot").PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rng _
        )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19178/discussion-between-kmiao91-and-scott)