# Run-Time Error 1004 - Macro to update pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to update a pivot table using a macro since data is added to the bottom of the table each month (Update to include data to last row).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pivot()

Dim shConD As Worksheet
Dim shPvtTbl As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set shConD = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated_Data")
Set shPvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTables")

lr = shConD.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = shConD.Range("A1:F" & lr)

With shPvtTbl.PivotTables(3).PivotCache
     .SourceData = rng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True) 'Error appears here
     .Refresh
End With

End Sub
```

On the `.SourceData` line, I am getting run-time error 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error. Followed logic from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258001/vba-updating-source-data-for-pivot-table-to-end-of-row) and the continued [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19178/discussion-between-kmiao91-and-scott) . Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: do you really need vba code? if the data source is always same you can just record refresh macro and set it to a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Excel 2007 or later, then the simplest way to accomplish this is to make sure your PivotTable source data is an Excel Table (aka ListObject), and use the Table name  in the Change PivotTable Data Source as shown below.

Thanks to the magic of Tables, from that point on, whenever you add new data to your Table, it will expand automatically. And whenever you refresh the PivotTable it will always pick up that new data automatically. There will be no need to change the PivotTable data source ever again.

[image]

Comment: So many years of excel...didn't know this basic concept. Thanks a million buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code's comments) :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pivot()

Dim shConD As Worksheet
Dim shPvtTbl As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

' Added PivotTable variables
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache

Set shConD = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated_Data")
Set shPvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTables")

lr = shConD.Range("A" & shConD.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = shConD.Range("A1:F" & lr)

' set/update the PivotCache (with latest rng modifications
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rng.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))
' for DEBUG Only
Debug.Print PvtCache.SourceData

' set the PivotTable object
Set PvtTbl = shPvtTbl.PivotTables(3)
' for DEBUG Only
Debug.Print PvtTbl.Name

' refresh the PivotTable with the updated PivotCache
PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
PvtTbl.RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Comment: on the 2nd to last line, `PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache` , the following error occurs: Run-time error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KoderM16 you sure you have 3 `PivotTables` ? This code works for me, try the code (I've added a `Debug` section)

Comment: Yeah I do have 3. I tried numbers 1 to 10 in there with no luck. Exact same error. The pivot tables are filtered as I created a dashboard on a separate sheet with the graphs from them. Could this contribute to the problem?

Comment: @KoderM16 no, this is no related. what values did you get in the immediate window when running mycode ? (did you see the edit) ?

Comment: Sorry yes I did use the edited code. It comes back with PivotTable3

Comment: @KoderM16 and.. what's the string for `Debug.Print PvtCache.SourceData` ?

Comment: it is Consolidated_Data!R1C1:R85C6

Comment: @KoderM16 I have no idea... sorry

Comment: Alright bud, thanks for your troubleshooting efforts anyway!